# how to create a dynamic login page

Tags: php

please I need help creating a php login webpage for users of different departments..I've created the login page and registration page where users register with their name..password and department.. But in the login page, all they will enter is username and password..I need codes for php to automatically query the database and  redirect users to their specific department pages(which I have created) based on the department they used to register.I have also created mySQL databases where all these info is stoted.please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code

Comment: You can do it how you want, if you are not a programmer i suggest you to follow some guide

Comment: I am a programmer... My main issue is just d syntax for querying a database to produce info which will be used

Comment: For knowing the syntax you could check the documentation..

Comment: use SELECT query to get the data from the DB and then check it using PHP..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code for login..

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pwd=$_POST['pwd']; 

    $sel_query=mysqli_query("SELECT id,Email,Password,LastLogin FROM tableName WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$pwd'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sel_query)==0)
    {
        echo "Email ID or Password are Incorrect. Please try again";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Logged In Successfully";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

usethe query that return dept and the deatil of login user

```
  SELECT id,Email,Password,department FROM tableName WHERE Email='$user' AND Password='$pass'
```

then use if condition for the department to giove the permission for access.

```
if(department= 'dept name' ){
//for the department
}else if (another dept condition){
//for the department
}else{
//user not exist
}
```